# To bridge difference in height

Tags: word-choice

Is 'to bridge' a correct expression to use here:

> 'Elevators are used to bridge big differences in height.'

I can see [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bridge) that the verb *bridge* can be used to reduce differences between something, but I wanted to know if it was ok to use it with a difference in height as opposed to vertical distances, which is what a bridge usually does.

Comment: We don't do proofreading here. Have you looked up 'bridge'? Does the definition seem correct? What definition are using for it? What research of your own have you done? Which dictionary have you used? Do you have a difficulty with a **specific** definition?

Comment: I wanna second @δοῦλος's request. If you have problems concerning the definitions the dictionaries give, please highlight the problem.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was ok to use it with a difference in height as opposed to vertical distances, which is wat a bridge usually does.

Comment: If you look up 'bridge' in a dictionary such as Oxford Dictionary online, you can also see example sentences. And learn in what situations the word is used. You really need to make your own decision here. Because words can be used by many people in different ways, your question is really asking for an opinion. Some NES may say yes, some may say no. You could also look up 'bridge' in a thesaurus.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners Stack Exchange. Your question is fine, but needs to be edited to show that you understand the definition of the word, (for example, that as a verb it means something like *join* or *connect*), but that you want to know if it can have this meaning in the context given. You've shown all of this (in my judgment) in your comments (though I think you wanted to say "horizontal" instead of "vertical"). Otherwise, your question may be closed as off-topic. There is information about how to ask good questions and what kind of question to avoid under *help,* below.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add the information you've put in your comment into the question itself. Without such clarify remarks, a question can seem "lazy". With such information, people feel more enlightened, thinking, "Ah, now I see what is being asked about here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bridge is stationary, and spans a horizontal gap.  An elevator moves within a shaft to transport people vertically. This is not similar enough to make "bridge" an appropriate term.

You might say that an elevator allows people to "overcome" great differences in height, or to "traverse" vertical distances.

Answer (score 5):

There are two main meanings of the verb 'bridge'. See [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english-thesaurus/bridge). One refers to connecting across horizontal spaces.

Another is more metaphorical and means to connect ideas or groups.

One can argue that you can extend the meaning of 'bridge' to mean 'connect vertical gaps'.

One could argue that you can use the metaphorical meaning and apply it to a vertical span.

The meanings of words are constantly changing. People apply words to new situations all the time.

I do not think it is a question of wrong or right here. You *could* use 'bridge'. Whether it is the most appropriate word is a matter of opinion. You could look up 'bridge' in a thesaurus and perhaps find a better word.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I don't know of a reason why you cannot use "bridge" in this manner, but I wouldn't do it. The problem is that an elevator is used for vertical movement, while a bridge is largely used for horizontal movement. Combining elevator and bridge in the same sentence is likely to produce the image of a bridge turned on end, and this is so incongruous that it will seem very odd.